# Cannot connect to Prosys OPC UA Simulation Server using node-opcua

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, opc-ua, node-opcua

I am trying to build an opcua client using the node-opcua library and I am testing it by trying to get it to connect to the Prosys OPC UA Simulation Server. I used the basic client example to attempt a connection but it doesn't seem to work and I can't make sense of the error message.

The code:-

```js
import {
    OPCUAClient,
    MessageSecurityMode,
    SecurityPolicy,
    AttributeIds,
    makeBrowsePath,
    ClientSubscription,
    TimestampsToReturn,
    MonitoringParametersOptions,
    ReadValueIdOptions,
    ClientMonitoredItem,
    DataValue,
} from "node-opcua";

const connectionStrategy = {
    initialDelay: 1000,
    maxRetry: 1
};

const client = OPCUAClient.create({
    applicationName: "MyClient",
    connectionStrategy: connectionStrategy,
    securityMode: MessageSecurityMode.None,
    securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy.None,
    endpointMustExist: false
});

const endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://localhost:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer"

async function main() {
    try {
        console.log("attempting to connect...");

        // step 1 : connect to
        await client.connect(endpointUrl);
        console.log("connected !");

        // // step 2 : createSession
        // const session = await client.createSession();
        // console.log("session created !");

        // step 3 : browse

        // step 4 : read a variable with readVariableValue

        // step 4' : read a variable with read

        // step 5: install a subscription and install a monitored item for 10 seconds

        // step 6: finding the nodeId of a node by Browse name

        // close session

        // disconnecting
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("An error has occurred : ", err);
    }
}
main();
```

The error message:-

```
attempting to connect...
An error has occurred :  AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:

  (0, assert_1.default)(s.length <= maxLength)

    at parseBitString (C:\Users\binahmad\Documents\SWE\code\1 - Projects\20230717_opcua_Interface_testing_tool\sample-node-opcua-client\node_modules\node-opcua-crypto\source\asn1.ts:91:15)
    at _readBitString (C:\Users\binahmad\Documents\SWE\code\1 - Projects\20230717_opcua_Interface_testing_tool\sample-node-opcua-client\node_modules\node-opcua-crypto\source\asn1.ts:113:16)
    at _readSubjectPublicKeyInfo (C:\Users\binahmad\Documents\SWE\code\1 - Projects\20230717_opcua_Interface_testing_tool\sample-node-opcua-client\node_modules\node-opcua-crypto\source\crypto_explore_certificate.ts:552:44)
    at readTbsCertificate (C:\Users\binahmad\Documents\SWE\code\1 - Projects\20230717_opcua_Interface_testing_tool\sample-node-opcua-client\node_modules\node-opcua-crypto\source\crypto_explore_certificate.ts:665:40)
    at exploreCertificate (C:\Users\binahmad\Documents\SWE\code\1 - Projects\20230717_opcua_Interface_testing_tool\sample-node-opcua-client\node_modules\node-opcua-crypto\source\crypto_explore_certificate.ts:714:29)
    at publicKeyAndPrivateKeyMatches (C:\Users\binahmad\Documents\SWE\code\1 - Projects\20230717_opcua_Interface_testing_tool\sample-node-opcua-client\node_modules\node-opcua-crypto\source\public_private_match.ts:30:33)
    at C:\Users\binahmad\Documents\SWE\code\1 - Projects\20230717_opcua_Interface_testing_tool\sample-node-opcua-client\node_modules\node-opcua-client\source\verify.ts:131:39
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\binahmad\Documents\SWE\code\1 - Projects\20230717_opcua_Interface_testing_tool\sample-node-opcua-client\node_modules\node-opcua-client\dist\verify.js:8:71 
    at new Promise (<anonymous>) {
  generatedMessage: true,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

I feel like it should be working but something might be wrong with my system or my node instead of the code.

I tried connecting to the server with UaExpert and that worked, I also tried connecting with a python script and it worked. Its just node that seems affected.

Node version: v16.15.0

node-opcua version: ^2.108.0

If anyone could help me figure out how to simply connect, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of investigating and posting on some other forums, one of the developers of node-opcua answered saying they've been refactoring and caught some bugs. It seems I've just been unlucky and was caught in the middle of this bug fixing. **Basically in the end it was a bug in the node-opcua library itself. This was fixed in node-opcua version 2.110.0 as seen [here](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/issues/1289#issuecomment-1682829525).**

In summary, I needed to do a few things to properly "clean" my system to get a fresh start:

1. Updated Node from v16.15.0 to v18.17.1
2. deleted folder C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\node-opcua-default-nodejs
3. Changed node-opcua **and** node-opcua-client to both use version 2.110.0
4. Then, of course, ran `npm install` to get the new packages

I could then connect to the Prosys Server and read a value with no issues with the following (simplified) script:

```js
const { OPCUAClient, AttributeIds } = require("node-opcua");
(async ()=>{
    const client  = OPCUAClient.create({ endpointMustExist: false });
    client.on("backoff",(retry,delay)=>{
        console.log("backoff",retry,delay);
    });
    const endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://<system name>:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer";
    await client.withSessionAsync(endpointUrl, async (session)=>{
        const dataValue = await session.read({ nodeId: "ns=3;i=1003", attributeId: AttributeIds.Value});
        console.log("Local server time is ", dataValue.value.toString());
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same error from the node-opcua package when trying to create a simulated server. This fails when running in a container using node version 14.16.1 but works if I run it on my system that has node version 16.15.1. You might try a newer version of node or an older version of node-opcua.

I have reverted back to using node-opcua version 2.50.0 and both initializing the server and connecting to it are working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Seems like it was a bug in the node-opcua library itself, I just posted a solution to the question.  It might even work for you if you ever decide to update :)